# How to display img file in django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I know the title is a bit misleading but I explain everything. I am in the process of creating a store in django and there is a small problem that I do not know how to work around. Well, for each product I want to assign several photos that I save in the database. That's why I created the `Photo` model, which is connected to the `Book` model with a `ForeignKey`.

The whole problem is that I do not know how to indicate on the store's home page one of the photos that is assigned to a specific book. Of course, there are many books on the page that are generated in a `for loop`.

If it is helpful, I save the pictures for each book in a separate folder, the function `content_file_name` is responsible for that

Of course, I am open to other ideas to achieve such an effect as described above. I am not sure if the path I have chosen is optimal.

```py
#models.py

def content_file_name(instance, filename):
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename = "%s.%s" % (instance.book.slug, ext)
    return os.path.join('books_img', instance.book.slug, filename)


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    publisher = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Photo(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.ImageField(default=random_img, upload_to=content_file_name)
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: A bit unclear actually

Comment: You want to add a photo on the home page and e.g type the name of the book below it?

Comment: In short words yes

Comment: Await my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a relation problem more than a coding problem. Let's dive into it

This is a short version of your `Book` class for illustration.

```
class Book(models.Model):
    pass
```

This is a short version of your `Photo` class for illustration.

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.ImageField(default=random_img, upload_to=content_file_name)
```

What's a `ForiegnKey` ?
- `ForiegnKey` is just a fancy name for `ManyToOne` right?, What's the many here and what's the one?

Well, We have a book that has multiple photos. So the photo has a `Key`, like a door key, It opens *ONLY* it's door, It's a `Key`.

Your `Photo` class has a class variable called book. Calling it will be like `Photo.book`. However, Because django acts too, Calling the reverse relation will be `book.photo_qs` where `photo_qs` is the default name for the reverse relations.

Let's improve it.

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='photos')
    file = models.ImageField(default=random_img, upload_to=content_file_name)
```

Now, As before, It's still `photo.book` but `book.photos` (from the related name)

In English, Every book instance has .photos (of related manager type). So if you get a book like

```
my_book = Book.objects.all()[0]
```

This book has .photos of type (Related Manager), Using it will be like

```
my_book.photos.all()
```

It's ok till here, Now the problem is that you want to send the image with it's book details in a template,

Your view is

```
def my_view(request):
    my_book = Book.objects.all()[0] # first book
    return render(request, 'my_template_path', context= {
        'my_book': my_book,
        })
```

Now your template has access to `my_book` variable.

in your template

```
{% for photo in my_book.photos.all %}
        <img src="{{ photo.file.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Edit according to your needs.