# Django: How to add model class inside class or refer?

Tags: python, django

I have a class called artist which is a profil for an artist

```
class Artist_object(models.Model):
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    Biography = models.TextField(default='Bitte Biography eingfügen', null=False)
```

now I want that this artist can have multiple paintings with a desrciption.

```
class Artist_painting(models.Model):
    painting1 = models.ImageField()
    painting1_desc = models.CharField(max_length=120, default=None)
    painting2 = models.ImageField()
    painting2_desc = models.CharField(max_length=120, default=None)
```

How can I put class Artist_painting inside the Artist_object that for every artist I view (i got
`def get_absolute_url(self):  return f'/artist/{self.id}'`
) it have an description for every image ?

Comment: You can use a `ForeignKey`.

Comment: Why are there two `painting` fields here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a relation, `ManyToOne`, Many `Painting`s for each `Artist`, `ManyToOne` relation is called `ForiegnKey` because the `Artist` himself is a key to the `Painting`, Each `Painting` has only one `Artist`.

```
class Artist(models.Model): 
    """
    no need to call it Artist_object, Stick with pep8 (ArtistObject)
    or better yet, Artist only because it's an object anyways.
    """
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    Biography = models.TextField(default='Bitte Biography eingfügen', null=False)

class Painting(models.Model):
   """
    Same naming rules apply
   """
   artist = models.ForiegnKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCASE, related_name="paintings")
```

- What's the related name?

  `artist` is a class variable, Calling the `artist` variable from a `Painting` instance is by using `painting_instance.artist`, What if we wanted to get the `Painting`s associated with an artist, It's by using `artist_instance.related_name` and in this case, It's `artist_instance.paintings`, If you didn't specify a `related_name`, It will be `painting_qs` by default, If you don't want to have access to the `reverse relation`, I mean the `.paintings`, Use `related_name="+"`
- What's `CASCASE` ?

  It's a basic SQL phrase which means, when the `Artist` gets deleted, delete his `Painting`s too.

refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60876212/how-to-display-img-file-in-django-template/60877112#60877112) to get more details about `ForiegnKey`

Answer (score 1):

You refer to a model with a [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey):

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    biography = models.TextField(default='Bitte Biography eingfügen')

class Painting(models.Model):
    painting = models.ImageField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, default=None)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(
        'Artist',
        related_name='paintings',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

You can access the `Painting` objects of an `Artist` with `some_artist.paintings.all()`.