# Django - Bootstrap for loop doesnt iterate through all objects

Tags: django, database, bootstrap-4

I got a Django app with bootstrap and i want to display an image preview so i made a small view of the image and after clicking it, it should appear over the whole screen. So i did this:

```
<img class="painting " src="{{ paintings.Gemälde.url }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-xl" />
        <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-xl" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myExtraLargeModalLabel"
            aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h5 class="modal-title mx-auto" id="exampleModalLongTitle">"{{ paintings.Bildname }}"</h5>
                    <img class="painting-active" src="{{ paintings.Gemälde.url }}">
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <p class="mx-auto">{{ paintings.Bildtechnik }}, {{ paintings.Erstelldatum }}, {{ paintings.Bildmaße_in_cm }}cm
                            {% if paintings.Bildpreis == 0 %}
                            </p>
                            {% else %}
                            {{ paintings.Bildpreis }}
                            {% endif %}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This code is inside a for loop `{% for paintings in artist.paintings.all %}`, more code is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60917577/django-how-to-add-model-class-inside-class-or-refer/60918892#60918892)

So if I click a picture it shows all the attributs of the first saved object. But if I remove the codeblock above and replace it with a simple list

```
<ul>
  <li> {{ paintings.name }} </li>
  <li> {{ paintings.etc }} </li>
</ul>
```

everything is shown correctly. Is this a problem with bootstrap or is there a stupid mistake of myself? I use django version 3.

Comment: You need a unique identifier for every modal. Preferably selected using id instead of class.

Comment: oh yes.. of course :D thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

ok, problem is in your html code. Your have to use fore loop like it.....

```
{%for items in paintings %}
<img class="painting " src="{{ paintings.Gemälde.url }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-xl" />
        <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-xl" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myExtraLargeModalLabel"
            aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h5 class="modal-title mx-auto" id="exampleModalLongTitle">"{{ paintings.Bildname }}"</h5>
                    <img class="painting-active" src="{{ paintings.Gemälde.url }}">
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <p class="mx-auto">{{ paintings.Bildtechnik }}, {{ paintings.Erstelldatum }}, {{ paintings.Bildmaße_in_cm }}cm
                            {% if paintings.Bildpreis == 0 %}
                            </p>
                            {% else %}
                            {{ paintings.Bildpreis }}
                            {% endif %}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
{%endfor%}

<!--if your views section is fine it will work for sure-->
```

Comment: Please use markdown formatting to make your code more readable. Welcome to StackOverflow!