# Django: DB-Query inside for a class in "models.py"

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

Good day,

inside my "models.py" in Django I want to create a new class called "Coworker" with these attributes

```
class Coworker(models.Model):

    roles = (
        ('Role A', 'Role A'),
        ('Role B', 'Role B'),
    )

    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, choices=roles)
    supervisor = models.CharField(...?)
```

I also want to create a "supervisor", which should look into this class and show me all the "fullname" with - let's say - "Role A" as choices. So of course in the beginning this field will be emtpy.

Is this possible? The function "db_column" doesn't seem to work. Or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing 2 points, Lemme illustrate

- The fact that you have a Coworker model that is not a **User** model.
  I mean, The Coworker is a user, Let's code this idea

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()
class Coworker(models.Model):
    ..........
    user = models.OneToOneField(User...., on_delete=..)
    supervisor = models.OneToOneField(User...., on_delete=..)  # **
```

or better if you want multiple supervisors, remove the line at ** and create this

```
class Supervisor(models.Model):
    coworker_supervised = models.ForiegnKey(Coworker, on_delete...,related_name='supervisors')
```

this implies `supervisor_instance.corworker_supervised` and `coworker.supervisors`

or better, use `m2m` if the supervisor can supervise multiple users and the user can have multiple supervisors.

- DRY principle, Just don't repeat yourself, The user has a `first_name`, `last_name`, if you want a `full_name`, define a method on the user that returns `first_nam` & `last_name` concatenated.

refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60917577/django-how-to-add-model-class-inside-class-or-refer/60918892#60918892) question.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem! Didn't saw it from this perspective.